# How to create a datetime variable with 2 columns (date) and (varchar)

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am wanting to create an update statement that will run for records that are 30 minutes older than the time at which the update runs:

```
Update Orders
set ordertype = 'q'
where createddaytime <= DATEADD(mi, -30, GETDATE())
```

However, I do not have a column `createddaytime`.
I have a `createdate` column, which is stored at datetime.  I also have a `createtime` column, which is `varchar(8)`.  6:30 pm would show as 18.5 in the column.

How can I create a `createdaytime` variable with those two columns?
When I try cast or convert on the time column I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: If your createdate column is datetime, it contains date and time. Why are you storing time in createtime?

Comment: The createdate column is formatted as datetime, but does not contain time data.  So for all records created today, createdate shows as 2015-11-29 00:00:00.000

Comment: Aha, I see. Thank you @MattC. At some point it might help you to store date and time in createdate column and remove createtime column altogether.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? You should probably move to using the appropriate data types for the data being stored as soon as possible like @zedfoxus suggested.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot control the column datatypes, they are set & controlled by the software that uses them (Sage 100).

Comment: Oh yeah - Sage! I've come across Sage's interesting ways of handling data before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this out:

```
update orders
set ordertype = 'q'
where
cast(
    cast(cast(createdate as date) as varchar(20)) + ' ' +  
    cast(floor(createtime) as char(2)) + ':' + cast(floor((createtime-floor(createtime))*60) as char(2)) + ':00'
  as datetime) <= dateadd(mi, -30, getdate())
```

Above - I've casted-down from datetime to date and the joined the 18.5 hours in the form of 18:30:00 to create a datetime.

Below is an example on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/634e4/12 and cater it to your needs.

```
create table orders (createdate datetime, createtime decimal(5,2));
insert into orders values ('2015-01-01 00:00:00', 18.5);
insert into orders values (getdate(), 18.5);

select 
  cast(
    cast(cast(createdate as date) as varchar(20)) + ' ' +  
    cast(floor(createtime) as char(2)) + ':' + cast(floor((createtime-floor(createtime))*60) as char(2)) + ':00'
  as datetime) as fld1
from orders;
```

Result:

```
|                       fld1 |
|----------------------------|
|  January, 01 2015 18:30:00 |
| November, 30 2015 18:30:00 |
```

Comment: Appears to be working correctly.  Thank you SO much!

Comment: Why go through the hassle to build a string by casting the existing `datetime` column, only to cast it back to a `datetime`? This seems sub-optimal at the very least...

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution & not tested, but should work :

```
Update Orders
set ordertype = 'q'
where (convert(datetime, convert(varchar(10), createdate, 111) +' ' + createddaytime)) <= DATEADD(mi, -30, GETDATE())
```

NOTE: You must store time as part of the DATETIME field itself i.e. createdate

Comment: Does it make more sense (or make it easier) just use two where clauses?
`Where datecreated = getdate and timecreated <= getdate + 30 mins`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will probably work:

```
-- Formatted to avoid scroll bar
Update Orders
set ordertype = 'q'
where 
  -- Cast the time to a number, multiply by 60 and add that to the date
  DATEADD(minute, CAST(createtime AS DECIMAL(5,3)) * 60, createdate) 
  <= DATEADD(minute, -30, SYSUTCDATETIME())
```

Keep in mind that the create date will be [truncated to the minute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) with this approach (6:30.59pm becomes 6:30.00pm). My approach also assumes clean data in the form you mentioned (18.5 for 6:30pm).